# Access efficiency of C++ 2D array

Tags: c++, performance, caching

I have a 2D array `a1[10000][100]` with 10000 rows and 100 columns, and also a 2D array `a2[100][10000]` which is the transposed matrix of `a1`.

Now I need to access 2 columns (eg. the 21th and the 71th columns) of `a1` in the order of `a1[0][20]`, `a1[0][70]`, `a1[1][20]`, `a1[1][70]`, ..., `a1[9999][20]`, `a1[9999][70]`. Or I can also access `a2` to achive the same goal (the order: `a2[20][0]`, `a2[70][0]`, `a2[20][1]`, `a2[70][1]`, ..., `a2[20][9999]`, `a2[70][9999]`). But the latter is much faster than the former. The related code is simplified as follows (`size1` = 10000):

```
1  sum1 = 0;
2  for (i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
3      x = a1[i][20];
4      y = a1[i][70];
5      sum1 = x + y;
6  } // this loop is slower
7  a_sum1[i] = sum1;
8
9  sum2 = 0;
10 for (i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
11     x = a2[20][i];
12     y = a2[70][i];
14     sum2 = x + y;
15 } // this loop is faster
16 a_sum2[i] = sum2;
```

Accessing more rows (I have also tried 3, 4 rows rather than 2 rows in the example above) of `a2` is also faster than accessing the same number of columns of `a1`. Of course I can also replace Lines 3-5 (or Lines 11-14) with a loop (by using an extra array to store the column/row indexes to be accessed), it also gets the same result that the latter is faster than the former.

Why is the latter much faster than the former? I know something about cache lines but I have no idea of the reason for this case. Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd loop is faster because of caching, 1st loop accesses elements far away, 2nd loop accesses elements next to reach other.

Comment: @Kaldrr Thank you. But x and y in the same iteration of the 2nd loop are far away from each other (eg. a2[20][0] and a2[70][0]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can benefit from the memory cache if you access addresses within the same cache line in a short amount of time. The explanation below assumes your arrays contain 4-byte integers.

In your first loop, your two memory accesses in the loop are 50*4 bytes apart, and the next iteration jumps forward 400 bytes. Every memory access here is a cache miss.

In the second loop, you still have two memory accesses that are 50*400 bytes apart, but on the next loop iteration you access addresses that are right next to the previously fetched value. Assuming the common 64-byte cache line size, you only have two cache misses every 16 iterations of the loop, the rest can be served from two cache lines loaded at the start of such a cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made the stupid mistake of considering only one cache line...

Answer (score 2):

This is because C++ has a row-major order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). You should avoid column-major access in C/C++ (https://www.appentra.com/knowledge/checks/pwr010/).

The reason is that the elements are stored by rows and the access by rows allows to better use cache lines, vectorization and other hardware features/techniques.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is cache locality.

`a2[20][0]`, `a2[20][1]`, `a2[20][2]` ... are stored in memory next to each other. And `a1[0][20]`, `a1[1][20]`, `a1[2][20]` ... aren't (the same applies to `a2[70][0]`, `a2[70][1]`, `a2[70][2]` ...).

That means that accessing `a1[0][20]`, `a1[1][20]`, `a1[2][20]` would waste DRAM bandwidth, as it would use only 4 or 8 bytes of each 64-byte cache line loaded from DRAM.